# How do I use variables in document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, variables, getelementbyid

I have this code which I've been trying to fix for hours.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    <!--

    function generate(){
    var titels = new Array();
    var i = 0;
    for(i;i<9;i++){
    var test = 'h1-0'+ i;
        titels[i] = document.getElementById(test).textContent;
    }

    document.getElementById("uitkomst").value = titels[1];      
    }
    -->
</script>
```

This gives me the error

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
titels[i] = document.getElementById(test).textContent;
```

But when I change 'h1-0'+i  by 'h1-0'+5 it does work and I don't get an error, so how do I fix this? Why is Javascript so annoying when using variables?

Comment: One of those "id" values you're generating does not correspond to an element on your page.

Comment: Thanks for the easy answer :) by just saying that you saved me a ton of work.

Answer (score 1):

Add another variable:

```
  var element;
```

and use it in the loop to hold on to the result of fetching (or trying to fetch) the element:

```
for (i; i < 9; i++) {
  element = document.getElementById('h1-0' + i);
  if (element) {
    titles[i] = element.textContent;
  }
  else {
    console.log("Element " + i + " not found.");
  }
}
```

Then check the console to see which one is missing.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can fix this issue - you can test for a missing object and skip that case or you can catch the exception that is thrown and act accordingly in the exception handler.

Here's how you could handle missing objects in your code:

```
function generate(){
    var titels = [];
    var i, item, test;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        test = 'h1-0'+ i;
        item = document.getElementById(test);
        if (item) {
            titels[i] = item.textContent;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("uitkomst").value = titels[1];      
}
```

If, this is really all your code is doing, then you don't need the `for` loop because you're only using the `[1]` item from the array and you can do this:

```
function generate() {
    var item = document.getElementById("h1-01");
    if (item) {
        document.getElementById("uitkomst").value = item.textContent;
    }

}
```